# how to group my collections by attribute?

Tags: meteor, collections

I got a collection with

```
 {categories:"category 1",name:"etc1"},{categories:"category 1",name:"etc2"},{categories:"category 2",name:"etc3"},{categories:"category 2",name:"etc"}.
```

so, in the Fetch... how can I group by categories?

Answer (score 2):

Meteor can't do this on its own but you can use underscore to do that:

```
//results from .fetch()
var results = [{categories:"category 1",name:"etc1"},{categories:"category 1",name:"etc2"}....

var grouped = _.groupBy(results, function(item) {
                  return item.categories;
              });
```

You should get something like this back:

```
{"category 1":[{"categories":"category 1","name":"etc1"},{"categories":"category 1","name":"etc2"}],"category 2":[{"categories":"category 2","name":"etc3"},{"categories":"category 2","name":"etc"}]}
```